# Running Spring web from IDE vs from jar file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, executable-jar

I am trying to create a simple web application that will use angular in FE and Spring in BE.

[image: This is my setup]

Everything works if I run it from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2), but if I start the jar file it cant find the jsp page and shows an Whitelabel Error Page.

[image: Whitelabel Error Page]

Its gradle build and thease are the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
}
```

**ChartConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ChartConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);

}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

}
```

**ChartInitializer.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class ChartInitializer extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ChartConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter() };
    return singleton;
}

}
```

**IndexController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndexPage() {
    return "ChartManagement";
}

}
```

And my jsp page contains only a

tag, nothing else.

What am I doing wrong, I cant figure it out?

Comment: `/WEB-INF` != `/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF`, move your `WEB-INF` folder to be directly rooted in `src/main/resources`

Comment: Tried it just now. This way it does not start from IDE also.

Comment: You've got a packaging issue.

Comment: What are JSPs doing in an Angular app?

Comment: I can change it to html file, currently I just want it to start. But I did not quite understand your first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work but with a little bit different configuration. I have removed

- ChartConfiguration.java
- ChartInitializer.java
- Everything inside main/resources folder

And now I have created a folder in main/resources called templates, and inside it is **index.html**

Also I have added a new dependency

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

And changed IndexController to

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndexPage() {
    return "index";
}

}
```